# Why does "seit langem" take a masculine/neuter ending?

Tags: gender, adverb, adjective-ending, time, nominalization

Why not "seit langer" instead, since the phrase seems to imply "seit langer Zeit"? What's the underlying noun that makes lange take an -m, or is there something else going on?

Comment: Interesting etymological question. Note that since the reforms "seit Langem" is an allowed or even recommended variant indicating that the noun is "das Lange". "langem" (*Dativ*) is an adjective with characteristics of nominalisation, see [the rules](https://www.dwds.de/d/orthografie#r58) (section 3.2).

Comment: The phrase could be older than our current common vocabulary. Perhaps it dates back to a time when a word other than 'Zeit' was the obvious completion.

Comment: Isn't it simply that *seit* requires the dative? *Seit langer* Zeit ist fine, too, but in that case *Zeit* is in the dative and *langer* only an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

"Seit langem" is in fact a proverbial phrase coming from "das Lange" (*the long [one]*). "Das Lange" would be the case of an adjective made noun and is, as the article shows, neutral.

Comment: Is that a well-known fact or just something you thought up? Is there any evidence or reference you can provide?

Comment: @DavidVogt: Would pointing to the general rule that adjectives/adverbs made nouns are always neutral ("das Große", "das Blaue", "das Weite", ...) suffice or do you want more specific evidence for "das Lange"?

Comment: I don't see why the construction should derive from the noun when the noun isn't used to refer to time in other contexts. Why do you think *seit langem* comes from *seit dem Langen*?

Comment: I think that, because "lang" has - among others - a temporal connotation. "Langeweile" shows that and "das Stück hat Längen" also means something like *not enough action for too much time*. There are also "längst" or "unlängst" coming undoubtedly from "lang" and having a temporal meaning. Furthermore, "Seit Langem" (capitalized) is the recommended way to write it. Why would it be capitalized if not fro being a noun?

Comment: If that is your reasoning, feel free to edit it into the post. It's just that one-line answers aren't really helpful. (I'll still disagree with the reasoning; disregarding *Längen*, which is feminine, all your examples use adjectives or adverbs, so I don't see how *das Lange* enters into it. I think we can ignore the fact that in 2006 someone decided to change the spelling; the official rules even call it an adjective, see p. [65](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf)).